# Npm Sass Warning

Tags: npm, sass, command

I typed  `npm install -g sass`  while installing sass with the command prompt. Gave this error:

`npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: Please update to v 2.2.x`

Comment: Presumably sass (or maybe one of your other dependencies) depends on an older version of fsevents, there's not much you can do about that beyond encouraging the maintainers to update.

Comment: I have updated nodejs but it didn't happen. I did sass-css compile  with Koala.

Answer (score 0):

NPM usually gives these warnings because the maintainers may be using older deprecated dependencies. There's absolutely *nothing* you can do about this, apart from begging the maintainer to upgrade the dependencies.

Deprecated means that the package/dependency is either:

- that which is *completely* not maintained or
- that whose *version being used* is no longer maintained

Usually these warnings can be ignored, but do remember that the code is **still** deprecated. If you are the maintainer of any project, you should also upgrade to a newer version.

Hope this helped you :)